# How do I actually change the site name on a localized site?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, configuration

Even after changing the settings in `/admin/config/system/site-information`, the page title still contains "Drupal".

All external examinations of the site configuration (config table and exported files) show the new name.

I examined the function `template_preprocess_html()` in `theme.inc` (where the configuration value is supposed to be loaded and entered in the theme variables), and inserted the following var_dumps:

```
var_dump(\Drupal::config('system.site')->getRawData()['name']);
var_dump(\Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name'));
var_dump(\Drupal::config('system.site')->getOriginal('name'));
```

The resulting output is `string(12) "My Site Name" string(6) "Drupal" string(6) "Drupal"`.

The configuration value isn't overridden anywhere in the site's settings files either. All caches are cleared.

Why is `->get('name')` returning the wrong value even though `->getRawData()` contains the correct one?

Edit: I should probably add that this is a site with a non-English default language. That seems to be the cause of nearly all the configuration-related core bugs. However, the langcode of the `sytem.site` configuration entity is correctly set.

Edit: More digging reveals that the language module is indeed responsible for overriding the configured name with the default name.

Edit3: There doesn't appear to be a way to set the localized site information without editing the configuration externally. I exported it, deleted the file `language/de/system.site.yml` and re-imported, which fixed it. (In the production site, importing didn't remove the deleted configuration entity; I had to delete the language.de/system.site record from the config table directly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to translating the configuration entities and objects is the core module `config_translation` (Configuration Translation).

This provides extra routes for every form that edits site settings or config entities, which allow editing the translations of translation-enabled config strings.